# Android: display x^y

Tags: android, numbers, textview, raise

Some help please!
How can i display raised numbers in a TextView for Android.For example if you want to display some Celsius degrees you can do this:`textview.setText(number+"\u2103")` and your good to go but i can't find a way to do something like this for number^anothernumber.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Format the string as HTML and then use the html superscript tag `<sup>`:

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
String text = "x<sup>y</sup>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Likewise if you want a subscript use the `<sub>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can use simple html formatting:

```
String str = number + "<sup>" + anotherNumber + "</sup>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextViews ability to display html markup, this should work;

`textView.setText(android.text.Html.fromHtml("x<sup>y</sup>"));`